# link tracking with httpgetwrap and TreatAsContent

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email-tracking

I hope you guys are able to help me with my issue.

I have been working on making our mailings a bit more dynamic. Technically it works as desired, however I noticed that the links are not being redirected via the SFMC link tracking.

Therefore, for example we cannot related any page visit that is coming from a newsletter campaign to that specific campaign as there are no tracking parameters attached anymore when using the following setup.

**1)** In the template we have the following:

```
SET @HashedEmail = MD5(@Email)
SET @HashedKey = MD5(@SubKey)
SET @UnsubscribeURL        = "https://unsubscribe.ourdomain.de"
SET @UnsubscribeType = "Special"
```

**(2)** At the top of an email we got that:

```
SET @CustomUnsubURL = Concat(@UnsubscribeURL,@UnsubscribeType,"?recipient=",@HashedEmail,"&id=",@HashedKey)
```

**(3)** In a Data extension we store some HTML and the following:

```
%%=redirectto(@CustomUnsubURL)=%%
```

**(4)** An then, in every email we are just having the following to pull the content from the data extensions:

```
%%[
+++ FOOTER  +++
]%%
%%=TreatAsContent(@footer)=%%
```

**+++**
So What I did know: I changed **(3)** to

```
%%=redirectto(httpgetwrap|@SingleUnsubURL)=%%
```

Link is being redirected via the link tracking now.

However, I am aware of the the limitation of online the first 100 unique links being tracked correctly when using TreatAsContent.

I found a few other topics dealing with this challenge, but am not sure if my issue is the exact same as the others had.

**Final questions:**
Any idea on **a)** how to get around this issue or **b)** how to see if that setup is being dealt with differently by SFMC in Terms of tracking? How can I see if the 101st link is also uniquely tracked?

I hope someone can help :)

Best,
Lukas

Comment: In your concat you don't have anything between UnsubscribeURL and UnsubscribeType. So in the example, you would have `https://unsubscribe.ourdomain.deSpecial`.  Is this just a typo?

Comment: @Gortonington thanks for your answer, indeed just a typo as I slimlined my original code a bit and apparently I inserted that little typo.

Comment: I am not going to add this as an answer because it is far from best practice, but try using `%%=TreatAsContentArea(emailaddr,@footer)=%%` instead of `TreatAsContent()` I have found that for some reason this will work with link tracking on content pulled from a DE or externally in those edge cases where TreatAsContent will not. Now, if you need this to be unique per subscriber, you need to name it something dynamic (hence my `emailaddr`) or it will just cache it and reuse that content in all the emails in the job.

Comment: Be VERY careful with this though as TreatAsContentArea() was not meant to be used this way and with high frequency/volume can cause big issues.

Comment: thanks a lot! gonna try that!

Comment: Since you are saying 'be very careful' - what might be the big issues that might be caused?

Comment: It basically creates a content area in every email which takes processing and can slow down your send exponentially